# Why doesn't rebar compile my files?

Tags: erlang, rebar

It's been a while since I've done any Erlang and I wanted to get back into it and use `rebar` to do it. I have a simple module-test combo that I've verified compiles okay, but when I try and compile it through rebar, nothing happens:

```
PS C:\Users\Magnus\Programming\binlog_parser_demo> rebar co -vv
DEBUG: Consult config file "c:/Users/Magnus/Programming/binlog_parser_demo/rebar.config"
DEBUG: Rebar location: "c:/Users/Magnus/Programming/rebar/rebar"
DEBUG: is_rel_dir(C:/Users/Magnus/Programming/binlog_parser_demo) -> false
DEBUG: Available deps: []
DEBUG: Missing deps  : []
DEBUG: Plugins requested while processing C:/Users/Magnus/Programming/binlog_parser_demo: []
DEBUG: Predirs: []
==> binlog_parser_demo (compile)
DEBUG: Matched required ERTS version: 7.0 -> .*
DEBUG: Matched required OTP release: 18 -> .*
DEBUG: Min OTP version unconfigured
DEBUG: Postdirs: []
PS C:\Users\Magnus\Programming\binlog_parser_demo> ls -r

    Directory: C:\Users\Magnus\Programming\binlog_parser_demo

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----               3/9     15:42            src
d----               3/9     14:42            test

    Directory: C:\Users\Magnus\Programming\binlog_parser_demo\src

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---               3/9     14:43       2293 binlog_parser_demo.erl

Directory: C:\Users\Magnus\Programming\binlog_parser_demo\test

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---               3/9     14:51       2662 binlog_parser_demo_tests.erl
```

What am I doing wrong? The file structure is what I got when I ran the template `rebar create template=simplemod modid=binlog_parser_demo` (and replaced the generated files with my old prewritten ones). I've verified that `erlc` is in the path and available and that `erlc` can compile the files okay when run independently.

Comment: Good to know: Many Erlang shops are moving away from rebar and have started to use  [Erlang.mk](https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk) with great success. This could save you time and energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `.app.src` file to your `src` directory to define your application. The contents might look something like the following, but you'll need to adjust it to make it work properly for your case.

```
{application, binlog_parser, [
    {description, "Binlog Parser"},
    {vsn, "0.1"},
    {registered, []},
    {applications, [kernel, stdlib]}
]}.
```

See [the rebar "Getting Started" docs](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Getting-started) for more information.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I'm annoyed that rebar didn't complain about this when being run.